# What are the downsides of using firebase analytics without ad id (AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics, analytics

With iOS 14, Apple has introduced new privacy features. When installing firebase through cocoapods, one of the options is to install Analytics without IDFA collection capability.

```
# pod ‘Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport’
```

I would like to use that option but do not understand what the pitfalls or disadvantages of doing so would be down the line.

Comment: You have to request user's permission under iOS 14.5 or higher.

Comment: Thanks @ElTomato. To clarify it better, what are the disadvantages that I would have on firebase? are there firebase products that I will not be able to use if I decide to go with the AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport pod.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature helps attribute app installs to certain adds through the apple identifier they call IDFA (identifier for advertisers). It's immensely useful to measure effectiveness of ads not only for downloads and installs, but also for latter internal conversions in the app.

But it won't be used if a user doesn't opt in to be tracked starting from iOS 14. So the value of it is somewhat diminished, making the analysts working with an effectively bias-sampled data that won't extrapolate normally.

Anyhow, if you need to attribute the traffic you've purchased to the source/campaign you've bought it from, you'll need IDFA. Otherwise, you're perfectly fine using AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport.

Comment: So this is only relevant for apps that show ads, right? I'm ok then with AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport in case my app does not show advertisements.

Comment: No, this is only relevant for apps that pay to third parties to get more downloads.